# Upgrade the speed of the calculations

Tags: python

I really need to speed up calculation for my N-Body simulation but I really don't know what to do numpy(jit) doesn't seem to work that much and I'm out of options.

The code that I need to speed up is this:

```
def calcul():   
    mt[:,6:9]=0.0
    for b in range(0,n):       
        for a in range(b,n):
            F=0.0
            p=mt[b,0:3]-mt[a,0:3]            
            p2=p@p
            if p2 == 0 or math.sqrt(p2)  >= epsilon_2 :
                pass
            else:
                F=(g*mt[b,9:10]*mt[a,9:10]*p)/((p2+epsilon)**1.5)
            mt[a,6:9]+=F
            mt[b,6:9]+=-F
    mt[:,6:9]/mt[:,9:10]
    mt[:,3:6]+=mt[:,6:9]*times
    mt[:,0:3]+=mt[:,3:6]*times
 
for t in range(iteration):
     calcul()        
     print(t+1)
     a=np.append(a,mt[:,0:3],axis=0)
```

Comment: If you are really expecting some meaningful answers, you ought to give meaningful context to your code and the issue

Answer (score 0):

you are using a square root in a if statement. This takes time to calculate. Instead of `math.sqrt(p2)  >= epsilon_2` you can use `p2  >= epsilon_2**2`.

Comment: Also I don't know how does python deals with the 'or', but in cases where p2==0 you don't even needs to check on epsilon_2, so you can remove the 'p2  >= epsilon_2**2' from the if and change the else to 'elif p2  < epsilon_2**2'. This probably will speed up a little bit the program.